# Rectangles are not appearing the right way

Tags: csv, d3.js, data-visualization, rectangles

I'm trying to create some rectangles in D3 by getting data from a .csv file.

The rectangles are appearing but not in the right position. For example I want the first one to start for x=0 and y=0 but instead of that the y is wrong. And also I can not read properly from the file the Letters. It just show me "NaN" at the left axis but I want them to appear inside each rectangle.

My .csv file is this

```
x,y,width,height,color,txt
0,0,50,50,purple,A
80,40,100,400,blue,B
300,500,100,200,navy,C
320,306,100,100,green,D
800,500,50,50,red,E
850,550,150,100,gray,F
40,550,500,50,indigo,G
100,200,300,320,yellow,H
```

I also tried to translate all the triangles the same way I did for the axis but nothing happened, they were disappeared.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

.rect { fill-opacity:.50; stroke: rgb(60,100,200); stroke-width:1px;}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->     
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 1074 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 818 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
  .attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the data
  d3.csv("rectangles.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

// format the data
   data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.txt = +d.txt;
  });

 // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; })]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
   .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height})
   .attr("fill", function(d) {return d.color});

  svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("fill","red")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .text(function(d) {return d.txt});

 // add the x Axis
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

 // add the y Axis
 svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
});
 </script>
</body>
```

I want to create all the rectangles inside the two axis with the letters inside them.

Comment: if you don't set a `x` for the text it defaults to 0. Use `d.x+d.width` for domain calculation, sanitize the numbers, they are strings `d.x= +d.x; ...., but not for `d.txt`. position text in mid x,y coord of rect and use `text-anchor=middle`

Comment: Thank you. I will keep these in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `rects` the correct y-position is:

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) - d.height; })
```

Since you want the **bottom** of the `rect` to be placed at your y-position.

Your "txt" shows up as NAN because you cast it to a number with these lines:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.txt = +d.txt;
});
```

Just remove them.

To position the text the correct calculations are:

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) - d.height/2; })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + d.width/2; })
```

Which moves it to the center of the `rects`.

Here's it all put together.

**EDITS**

So this is more complicated then I thought.  The real y calculation is:

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return  y(d.y) - (height - y(d.height)); })
```

And the height is:

```
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.height); });
```

Update [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tmIcdcvuyijeBGrMWmWG?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you also explain to me how to fix the axis to be at the same range? Because the first rectangle begins for 0,0 with width and height 100. But at the axis the rectangle its below100 on both x,y..